# Could variable zero-initialization reduce performances?

Tags: arrays, c, performance, initialization, static-analysis

I am correcting static analysis (MISRA-C-2012) violations, one rule of which (rule 9.3) states that variables shall be initialized before use.

For instance:

```
void bar_read(int * array)
{
    printf("array[1]: %u\n",array[1]);    
}

void bar_write(int * array)
{
    array[1]=1;    
}

int main(void)
{
    #define FOO_SIZE 12
 #ifdef MISRA_VIOLATION_DISABLED
    int foo[FOO_SIZE]  = {0}; //ok
 #else
    int foo[FOO_SIZE]; //violation
 #endif
    bar_read(foo);
    bar_write(foo);
    bar_read(foo); 

    return 0;
}
```

Some collegues of mine declared that they were removing variables initialization (for big arrays) `foo[FOO_SIZE] = {0};` because it was reducing performances, which puzzled me.

In my understanding, zero-initialized variables are put in the bss section at compile time and there is no runtime performance impact.

Could I be wrong? Might it depends on the compiler? Is there any optimisation that makes it true?

Comment: The differences between `int foo[FOO_SIZE]  = {0};` and `int foo[FOO_SIZE];` should be resolved during compile-time. It is generally a good idea to zero-initialize, as a compiler may not do it for you. `foo` is local so it won't use the `.bss` section, it will be on the stack, regardless of zero-initialization. There shouldn't be any notable runtime performance impact, although the specific implementation may vary by compiler.

Comment: @h0r53 This is not true. `int foo[FOO_SIZE]  = {0};` adds runtime initialization, which costs performance. I saw on some architectures that it is being compiled into some variant of internal `memset`  call.

Comment: Fair. Unless you are absolutely certain that invalid array access won't take place, I would argue initialization is worth the seemingly minor performance penalty it may cost.

Comment: @h0r53 Sure, there might be other considerations except performance.

Comment: Adding to above comments: I am an embedded programmer, and like to think what is the use of my local array before deciding whether to initialize them to 0. a) if I know that I use it right away for sprintf(), which will zero terminate the string for me, I save the runtime overhead and do not initialize the array: `char buff[FOO_SIZE];`   b) if I use the array for any reading and must be sure that variables start with known value, I invest the runtime initialization time with:  `char buff[FOO_SIZE] = {0};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables defined inside of a function without the `static` keyword have **automatic storage duration**.  These variables are typically created on the stack when they come into scope.

This means that if such variables are initialized then there is a cost at runtime to initialize them.

Only variables with **static storage duration**, i.e. variables declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword, are typically defined in either .data if explicitly initialized or .bss if not.

When compiling this code under gcc 4.8.5 with `-O0`, defining `MISRA_VIOLATION_DISABLED` resulting in the following additional code:

```
subq    $48, %rsp
leaq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
movl    $0, %eax
movl    $6, %edx
movq    %rsi, %rdi
movq    %rdx, %rcx
rep stosq
```

Comment: does it make a difference for `-O2`?

Comment: If the other functions are reduced to declarations, the first two lines differ slightly but the rest is the same.

Answer (score 6):

An array defined with `int foo[FOO_SIZE]` (no `static` or `extern`) inside a function has automatic storage duration, meaning it is “created” (memory is reserved for it) each time execution reaches the block it is in and is “destroyed” (memory is released) when execution of that block ends. Because functions can be called recursively, memory for automatic objects cannot feasibly be reserved in the `.bss` section. The stack is generally used for them.

Further, even if they were in the `.bss` section, their lifetimes in the C model still begin and end each time the block they are in begins and ends. So, if they are initialized, they have to be initialized each time a new lifetime begins. Storing them in the `.bss` section would not save anything in this regard.

Further, if the `.bss` section is zero-initialized, that is not free. Whenever the operating system provides memory to back a zero-initialized section, it must clear that memory.

Comment: Aside: "Because functions can be called recursively,"  --> With select static analysis, a function can be identified as not re-entrant and use a fixed memory location.  Still likely incurs object initialization on each call - but possible in a fixed place.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` variables are instantiated at runtime, so any initialization also has to occur at runtime, which will incur some performance penalty - exactly how much depends on the compiler and level of optimization.

Having said that, your colleagues should not remove the initialization without doing one of two things:

- proving that there's no code that will try to read any array element before it is assigned;
- quantifying the performance loss ***and*** showing that it falls outside of some requirement or specification - e.g. "Requirement X says that this operation must complete in 100 ms or less, but with the initialization it's taking 120 ms" or something like that.

**EDIT**

For example, I changed the code to define the initializer as part of the build command, then I did some crude instrumentation with the `clock` library function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void bar_read( int *array )
{
  printf( "array[1]: %d\n", array[1] );
}

void bar_write( int *array )
{
  array[1] = 1;
}

int main( void )
{
  clock_t start = clock();
#ifndef FOO_SIZE
#define FOO_SIZE 2000
#endif

#ifndef INIT 
#define INIT
#endif

  int foo[FOO_SIZE] INIT ; // will expand to nothing or ={0} depending on build command
  bar_read( foo );
  bar_write( foo );
  bar_read( foo );

  clock_t end = clock();
  printf( "operation took %lu clocks (%f seconds)\n", end-start, (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
  return (int)(end-start);
}
```

So I can build with and without initialization and see if there's a difference in how long a run takes:

```
$ gcc -o init -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -DFOO_SIZE=2000 -DINIT="" init.c
$ ./init
array[1]: -1898976766
array[1]: 1
operation took 39 clocks (0.000039 seconds)

$ gcc -o init -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -DFOO_SIZE=2000 -DINIT="={0}" init.c
$ ./init
array[1]: 0
array[1]: 1
operation took 53 clocks (0.000053 seconds)
```

I have `main` return the number of clocks taken up by the main part of the program.  I then wrote a shell script to build the code with and without the array initializer, run each version a hundred times (bigger sample than we need, but it doesn't take that much time to run) and take the average of those runs (integer average, but good enough for illustration):

```
#!/bin/bash

INIT_PARAMS=( '""' '"={0}"' )
let runs=100

for INIT in "${INIT_PARAMS[@]}"
do
  cmd="gcc -o init -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -DFOO_SIZE=2000 -DINIT=${INIT} init.c"
  echo $cmd
  eval $cmd
  let x=0
  for i in `seq 1 1 $runs`
  do
    ./init >/dev/null # suppress output from init itself
    let x=$x+$?
  done
done
```

And the output I get is:

```
$ . init_test.sh 
gcc -o init -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -DFOO_SIZE=2000 -DINIT="" init.c
Average clocks per run for INIT="" is 24
gcc -o init -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -DFOO_SIZE=2000 -DINIT="={0}" init.c
Average clocks per run for INIT="={0}" is 33
```

So there is a definite penalty for initializing a 2000-element array of `int` as part of its declaration, and on average it's 9 clocks (0.000009 seconds), or a 37% increase, without any optimization.  Upping the optimization level would reduce that cost (probably), but not eliminate it completely.